# Updating OSM data

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm trying to keep my OSM PostGIS data up to date by reading this tutorial http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Minutely_Mapnik

The time periods are minute, hour and day, but I think a daily update is too much for me. Is there a way to import monthly ? Or every 15 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this yet but I have read about it and plan to implement something in the future.

Looks like you just need to edit "replication/minute" in configuration.txt.  Although it sounds like you should probably do a daily rather than a monthly because it would generate a larger change file to process.

> **Choose replication file interval**
>
> By default, osmosis will fetch minutely replication diffs, and at most
>   one hours worth of them. Should you want anything else, edit the
>   $WORKDIR_OSM/configuration.txt and change "replication/minute/" in the
>   baseUrl to "replication/hour" or "replication/day". If you have lots
>   to catch up, you can even set the value maxInterval=3600 higher. This
>   controls how much data Osmosis will download in one run.

Comment: Ahn.. understood. Small pieces every time is better than a large piece once. What about bandwidth?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't surmise about bandwidth.

Comment: As far as I remember the daily update needs almost a day to process, and needs fast hard disks. Since the diffs are globally, you can not simply add a diff of your study area.